# Why is “well-known” hyphenated?

Tags: hyphenation

*Well* is adverb and *known* is adjective. As far as I know, it should not be hyphenated. For example: *clearly impossible* task, *extremely powerful* processor.

Comment: "well" is an adverb, but it doesn't end in *-ly.* Related: [Hyphen: “well defined” vs. “well-defined”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/410283)

Answer (score 0):

For starters, many words associated with well seems to be hyphenated. `Well-fed`, `well-written`. Isn't this because of the fact that `clearly`, `impossible`, `extremely` and `powerful` are all adjectives, known, fed, and written are not. `Well-known` functions as an adjective as a whole, perhaps that is the reason why it is hyphenated.

```
This is a well-known person.
```

The use case here is that well-known was used as an adjective preceding a subject.

```
This person is well known.
```

The above statement works the other way.

Comment: *Clearly* and *extremely* are adverbs, not adjectives. *Known, fed*, and *written* can be adjectives or they can be verbs, and *known* can even be a noun. *Well* is an adverb in those instances.