# Hyphenation for a well toasted bagel

Tags: hyphenation

I’m curious whether, if one were to order a bagel, well toasted, if the correct hyphenation would be, “Hello, could I please get a well-toasted bagel?”

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hyphen: “well defined” vs. “well-defined”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/410283/hyphen-well-defined-vs-well-defined). [WordReference](https://www.wordreference.com/definition/well-toasted) has a long list of _well-Ved_ compounds, all hyphenated.

Comment: It would normally be a *well-toasted bagel*. But that would change in the context of something like *a **very** well toasted bagel* where the longer phrase warrants the lack of hyphenation. (This is a *Chicago Manual of Style* addition to *Associated Press*.)

Comment: SInce *well toasted bagel* is completely unambiguous (with or without a hyphen) it's a stylistic choice.